# How to find out if an arithmetic sequence exists in an array

Tags: arrays, math, sequence

If there is an array that contains random integers in ascending order, how can I tell if this array contains a arithmetic sequence (length>3) with the common differece x?

Example:
**Input:** Array=[1,2,4,5,8,10,17,19,20,23,30,36,40,50]
x=10
**Output:** True

Explanation of the Example: the array contains [10,20,30,40,50], which is a arithmetic sequence (length=5) with the common differece 10.

Thanks!

I apologize that I have not try any code to solve this since I have no clue yet.

After reading the answers, I tried it in python.
Here are my codes:

```py
df = [1,10,11,20,21,30,40]
i=0
common_differene=10
df_len=len(df)
for position_1 in range(df_len):
    for position_2 in range(df_len):
        if df[position_1] + common_differene == df[position_2]:
            position_1=position_2
            i=i+1
print(i)
```

However, it returns 9 instead of 4.

Is there anyway to prevent the repetitive counting in one sequence [10,20,30,40] and also prevent accumulating i from other sequences [1,11,21]?

Comment: No other constraints? What about the sizes of the integers? The size of the array?

Comment: Hi James, thanks for your reply. The integers in the array can range from 1 to 1,000,000. The size of the array is 5000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve your problem by using 2 loops, one to run through every element and the other one to check if the element is `currentElement+x`, if you find one that does, you can continue form there.
With the added rule of the sequence being more than 2 elements long, I have recreated your problem in FREE BASIC:

```
DIM array(13) As Integer = {1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 10, 17, 19, 20, 23, 30, 36, 40, 50}
DIM x as Integer = 10
DIM arithmeticArrayMinLength as Integer = 3
DIM index as Integer = 0

FOR position As Integer = LBound(array) To UBound(array)
    FOR position2 As Integer = LBound(array) To UBound(array)
        IF (array(position) + x = array(position2)) THEN
            position = position2
            index = index + 1
        END IF
    NEXT
NEXT
IF (index <= arithmeticArrayMinLength) THEN
    PRINT false
ELSE 
    PRINT true
END IF
```

Hope it helps

---

### Edit:

After reviewing your edit, I have come up with a solution in Python that returns all arithmetic sequences, **keeping the order of the list**:

```py
def arithmeticSequence(A,n):
    SubSequence=[]
    ArithmeticSequences=[]
    #Create array of pairs from array A
    for index,item in enumerate(A[:-1]):
        for index2,item2 in enumerate(A[index+1:]):
            SubSequence.append([item,item2])
    #finding arithmetic sequences
    for index,pair in enumerate(SubSequence):
        if (pair[1] - pair[0] == n):
            found = [pair[0],pair[1]]
            for index2,pair2 in enumerate(SubSequence[index+1:]):
                if (pair2[0]==found[-1] and pair2[1]-pair2[0]==n):
                    found.append(pair2[1])
            if (len(found)>2): ArithmeticSequences.append(found)
    return ArithmeticSequences

df = [1,10,11,20,21,30,40]
common_differene=10

arseq=arithmeticSequence(df,common_differene)
print(arseq)
```

**Output**: [[1, 11, 21], [10, 20, 30, 40], [20, 30, 40]]

This is how you can get all the arithmetic sequences out of `df` for you to do whatever you want with them.
Now, if you want to remove the sub-sequences of already existing arithmetic sequences, you can try running it through:

```py
def distinct(A):
    DistinctArithmeticSequences = A
    for index,item in enumerate(A):
        for index2,item2 in enumerate([x for x in A if x != item]):
            if (set(item2) <= set(item)):
                DistinctArithmeticSequences.remove(item2)
    return DistinctArithmeticSequences

darseq=distinct(arseq)
print(darseq)
```

**Output**: [[1, 11, 21], [10, 20, 30, 40]]

*Note*: Not gonna lie, this was fun figuring out!

Comment: Thank you Dušan! It is super helpful to me. I can now use your code to solve my problem that bothered me for days.

Comment: @qwe987 I have edited my answer. Please label the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try from 1: check the presence of 11, 21, 31... (you can stop immediately)

Try from 2: check the presence of 12, 22, 32... (you can stop immediately)

Try from 4: check the presence of 14, 24, 34... (you can stop immediately)

...

Try from 10: check the presence of 20, 30, 40... (bingo !)

You can use linear searches, but for a large array, a hash map will be better. If you can stop as soon as you have found a sequence of length > 3, this procedure takes linear time.

Answer (score 0):

Scan the list increasingly and for every element v, check if the element v + 10 is present and draw a link between them. This search can be done in linear time as a modified merge operation.

E.g. from 1, search 11; you can stop at 17; from 2, search 12; you can stop at 17; ... ; from 8, search 18; you can stop at 19...

Now you have a graph, the connected components of which form arithmetic sequences. You can traverse the array in search of a long sequence (or a longest), also in linear time.

In the given example, the only links are 10->-20->-30->-40->-50.